# What software was used for this video with zooming text transitions over landscapes?

Tags: software-recommendation, resource-recommendations, video, technique

I came across this fascinating [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDcvgSoL8cs). It zooms and pans around various landscape scenes, with flying text coming in and out of focus. Does anyone know what software they used for this?

I'm naive in this area, so any suggestions or ideas will be deeply appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please describe the video in words as well, in case the link goes dead in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely After Effects. Although it could also be done via Flash. Or even a combination of the two.

Comment: Agreed. I'd be very surprised if it wasn't using 3D layers in After Effects.